# InvalidTemplateDeployment error in creating app service through visual studio

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am following this [quickstart tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=netcore31&pivots=development-environment-vs) from Microsoft on creating a web app and deploying it to azure app service. When I try to create the app service, I am getting this error:

`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: {"error":{"code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","message":"The template deployment failed with multiple errors. Please see details for more information.","details":[{"code":"RequestDisallowedByPolicy","target":"AzureCDN-POC","message":"Resource 'AzureCDN-POC' was disallowed by policy. Policy identifiers: '[{\"policyAssignment\":{\"name\":\"CE Prevent - Web - TagsCompliance\",\"id\":\"/subscriptions/[subscription id]/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/CE Prevent - Web - TagsCompliance\"}`

What causes this error and how can  I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Resource 'AzureCDN-POC' was disallowed by ***policy***

Your Subscription Administrator has set a policy that disallows the creation of such resources.

You need to contact your Subscription Administrator, change the policy will solve your issue.

**For more details, please read official doc.**

[What is Azure Policy?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview)

**Related Post:**

[1. Resource was disallowed by policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61987966/resource-was-disallowed-by-policy)

[2. Azure course that tries to use Azure Cloud Shell fails with “RequestDisallowedByPolicy” using free account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59940105/azure-course-that-tries-to-use-azure-cloud-shell-fails-with-requestdisallowedby)